# Problema con strcat

Tags: c, string

Tengo un problema con un programa que me genera una clave, cuando hago debug me sale que se salta la sentencia `strcat` y no tengo ni idea porque hace eso.

```
void gClaves(tRegLista *reg,int i,int op)
{
int y;


char auxclave[5];
char numclave[4];


switch(op)
{
case 1:
    auxclave[0]='L';
    sprintf(numclave,"%d", reg->contadorLibros);

    if(reg->contadorLibros < 10)
    {
        for(y = 1; y < 4; y++)
        {
            auxclave[y] = '0';
        }
    }
    if(reg->contadorLibros >=10 && reg->contadorLibros < 100)
    {
        for(y = 1; y < 3; y++)
        {
            auxclave[y] = '0';
        }
    }
    if(reg->contadorLibros >=100)
    {
        auxclave[1]= '0';
    }
    //Concateno letra y numeros
    strcat(auxclave, numclave);
    //Copio el resultado de la union dentro de la posicion correspondiente al ejemplar y al campo de clave.
    strcpy(reg->ejemplar[i].idEjemplar, auxclave);
    //FUNCION PARA GENERAR CLAVE EN FUNCION DEL ARTICULO.
    break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char auxclave[5];
```

Ahí estás reservando 5 caracteres de la pila para una variable llamada `auxclave`. En este punto el contenido de la memoria puede ser cualquier combinación posible de 5 caracteres (para este caso y posteriores voy a indicar los caracteres basura con el símbolo `'~'`:

```
auxclave = '~~~~~';
```

Continuamos con la ejecución...

```
auxclave[0]='L';
```

Ahora inicializas el primer elemento del arreglo... el resto siguen teniendo basura. El nuevo estado del arreglo es:

```
auxclave = 'L~~~~';
```

Seguimos...

```
if(reg->contadorLibros < 10)
{
    for(y = 1; y < 4; y++)
    {
        auxclave[y] = '0';
    }
}
```

En el caso de que haya menos de 10 libros rellenas las posiciones 1 a 3 con `'0'`: `auxclave = 'L000~';`

```
if(reg->contadorLibros >=10 && reg->contadorLibros < 100)
{
    for(y = 1; y < 3; y++)
    {
        auxclave[y] = '0';
    }
}
```

En el caso de que el número de libros se encuentre entre 1 y 99... escribes un `'0'` en los bytes 2 y 3 del arreglo: `auxclave = 'L00~~';`

```
if(reg->contadorLibros >=100)
{
    auxclave[1]= '0';
}
```

en cambio si el número de libros es superior o igual a 100 entonces añades un único `'0'`: `auxclave ='L0~~~';`

Y ahora viene el error que tu detectas:

```
strcat(auxclave, numclave);
```

`strcat` intenta añadir una cadena al final de la otra. Para localizar el final de la cadena busca el caracter finalizador de cadenas `'\0'` que se encuentra en un lugar indeterminado porque **no has finalizado** `auxclave` convenientemente.

¿Solución? Inicializar la variable al declararla:

```
char auxclave[5] = {0};
```

De esta forma todos sus bytes estarán inicializados a `'\0'`. Otro error con el que te vas a encontrar es que, como la cadena ha de almacenar el correspondiente caracter finalizador la cadena tiene que tener un espacio extra reservado para este menester. Tu arreglo se queda corto por un caracter (5 caracteres visibles + finalizador = 6 caracteres requeridos). Lo correcto entonces es hacer lo siguiente:

```
char auxclave[6] = {0};
```

A modo de bonus, considera hacer uso de sentencias if-else:

```
if(reg->contadorLibros < 10)
{
    for(y = 1; y < 4; y++)
    {
        auxclave[y] = '0';
    }
}
else if(reg->contadorLibros < 100) // Si llega a este if es que contadorLibros>9
{
    for(y = 1; y < 3; y++)
    {
        auxclave[y] = '0';
    }
}
else // Te ahorras esta condición al completo
{
    auxclave[1]= '0';
}
```

O incluso puede quedarte más chulo con `sprintf`:

```
char auxclave[6] = {0};
sprintf(auxclave,"L%04i",reg->contadorLibros);
```